# "Today current local will be rain" makes sense?

Tags: grammar, listening

I'm studying English listening to CNN student news.

http://edition.cnn.com/2016/04/26/studentnews/sn-content-weds/index.html

At 5:54, the audio sounds like "Today current local will be rain" (also the script).
However, I think, but not sure, the sentence is grammatically broken. Shouldn't it be something like "Today, current locale will be raining" ?

FYI, The robot speaking the sentence is made in Japan, and that could be the reason why the sentence is grammatically wrong, I guess.

Anyway, I'd like to make sure if I am correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a technical glitch or a badly edited script, but I'm pretty sure *"Today current local will be rain"* is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "Today, current local will be rain" is not English. It may be Japlish.

Comment: I agree, it must be the word-to-word literal translation to English that's given this sentence no meaning at all.